# connecting between app in xamarin forms to a local server written in python

Tags: python, xamarin.forms, server, localhost

I'm sending a request through my app (on the client side) to the the server which is runing on the address 127.0.0.1:80
unfortunately the request doesn't get to the server and I get no response.

this is the code on the client side (written in xamarin.forms):

```
    private void SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://127.0.0.1:80/api/calculate_prices/" + 
        SearchBar.Text, string.Empty)); //change to local
        Call_api(uri);
    }
```

and this is the code on the server side (written in python):

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
def api_get_price(request, slug):
     if request.method == "GET":
         df_xlsx = pd.read_excel('ItemsList.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
         df = pd.DataFrame(df_xlsx.iloc[1])
         parsed = json.loads(df.to_json())
         return parsed
     return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

what am I missing?

Comment: You should try calling the api away from your app to determine whether the issue lies with your server or client. Use Postman, Powershell, Shell, etc to make a HTTP request. If that works then the issue lies in the forms app. You also should provide the implementation of the `Call_api` method since if theres an issue with the cleintside code, it's likely there

Comment: use the IP or FQDN, not `localhost` or the loopback address

Comment: If running the app on the Android emulator, use `10.0.2.2` instead of `127.0.0.1`.